# Microsoft Azure Map – Weather Preview

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-maps

**Hello**

I’m calling Weather - Get Hourly Forecast API, using C# back-end. As {query} I’m passing different LAT/LON coordinates from around the world and retrieve their forecasts.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/weather/gethourlyforecastpreview#hourlyforecast

**Question:**
How can I retrieve the forecast with the date/time zone of location, that I’m checking?
Right now, I can only get a forecast with the date/time of my initial request location.

Documentation is not providing information about any parameter, that could be pass, to change this.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That API returns the "date" property for each forecast in the ISO 8601 format, including the timezone offset.  So, while it does not explicitly list a timezone as a string, you can determine its timezone by parsing the offset from UTC.

If you are willing to make a separate API call, you can use the Get Timezone by Coordinates endpoint to pass in your lat/long and get the detailed zone info:

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/timezone/gettimezonebycoordinates

Endpoint: [https://atlas.microsoft.com/timezone/byCoordinates/json?api-version=1.0&query={query}](https://atlas.microsoft.com/timezone/byCoordinates/json?api-version=1.0&query=%7Bquery%7D)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for looking at this!

Unfortunately, the time zone offset from the ISO 8601 date format is always the same for a different location. Please have a look below:

Berlin
[image]

New York
[image]

Tokyo
[image]

Looks like it’s a bug or some kind of issue. I’ll report it on the GitHub project.

I’m marking the answer as solved, because my fallback scenario was also to use the time zone API.

Thank you for help.

Comment: You're correct.  I had not actually tested it with my own Maps Key, but it always returns +00:00.  It looks like someone already submitted a report on the Azure feedback site (not GitHub).  You can see that here:  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909172-azure-maps/suggestions/40997545-include-utc-offset-as-per-documentation-weather.  But it's been under review since August.

Comment: Thx, I’ve also added a comment there – I hope more votes will cause that it will get fixed faster. 
It’s still Preview so it was also expected, that, this small issue can show up. 
Anyway I’ve also posted an issue on Github https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/issues/51